# If certain dropdown, counting another number on the same row

Tags: google-sheets

This is pretty basic I'm assuming, but I'm rather inexperienced.

So I have a dropdown list of categories.
On every row I also have a column of numbers.
I want to have totals of each category's number.

Example:

- Dog 2
- Cat 1
- Duck 3
- Dog 4
- Cat 6

Total Dog: 6
Total Cat: 7
Total Duck: 3

Comment: There are many ways of doing that depending on what your spreadsheet looks like. Post a link to it or a screenshot if you want any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `query` for this. Assuming your data is in columns A:B, the query would look like

```
=query(A:B, "select A, sum(B) group by A")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you data sample is just a sample, I would favour a pivot table:

[image: WA107671 example]

`Animal` to Add field **Rows** and `No.` to Add field **Values**.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, I think `SUMIF` is a good option.

The syntax is `SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])`

See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en for more info.

For example,

```
|   |   A  | B | C |   D    |           E              |
|---|------|---|---|--------|--------------------------|
| 1 | Dog  | 2 |   | Totals |                          |
| 2 | Cat  | 1 |   | Dog    | =SUMIF(A1:A5, D2, B1:B5) |
| 3 | Duck | 3 |   | Cat    | =SUMIF(A1:A5, D3, B1:B5) |
| 4 | Dog  | 4 |   | Duck   | =SUMIF(A1:A5, D4, B1:B5) |
| 5 | Cat  | 6 |   |        |                          |
```

Columns D and E have the sum totals of columns A and B.

The first value is `A1:A5` because those cells have the column we are testing.

The second value is either `D2`, `D3`, or `D4`, depending on what we are testing against.

The third value is `B1:B5` because that have the values we want to sum.